# How to put some "\usepackage''s into one package?

Tags: packages, best-practices

Since I learnt to use LaTeX 1 month ago, I have never used other software.
But every time I begin to write a latex file, I will have to type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=2.0cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
```

So when you are writing C++ code, you just need to include some head files like parameter.h. So is there a way to write those `\usepackage`s in a file and then include it?

Comment: If you are not careful, it leads to great inflexibility, but try putting everything below `\documentclass` in a file called `mypreamble.sty` and then load it with `\usepackage{mypreamble}`.  (Note, though, that there are slightly 'better' ways to do this.)

Comment: FYI: `subfigure` is obsolete for about 10 years. I recommend to use `subcaption` instead.